# Example Grep search pattern to search for all text between two words

Tags: search, grep

I have multiple text files I need to extract a viable amount of characters between two specific words, "".

Can someone give me an example grep pattern that will find all characters of any kind, including spaces, between these two words so I can then replace with a blank space?  Thank you.

I don't have any example code I can put in my question, I am using a text editing program and I would like to find all the text between two unique words in the file and delete it, the text editing program allows the use of grep patterns.

Comment: Edit your question to show sample input and expected output as it's not clear at all what exactly you are trying to do. It SOUNDS like what you want is nothing to do with grep but instead might be something along the lines of `sed 's/(word1).*(word2)/\1 \2/'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below grep line to search pattern like **word1** something and other things and then **word2**

```
grep -o -E "word1(\b).*word2(\b)" file.txt
```

As you may notice this command's output also includes word1 and word2.